# Using Nightwatch.js page objects

Tags: node.js, selenium, browser, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I was wondering is there a way to use several page objects within one test without having to specify a url in each page object file.

All tests start on the login page launched using the `launch_url` parameter & navigate to several other URLS via button clicks

I want page objects to only contain element selectors.

I have tried using variable declarations such as

```
 `var loginButton = loginPage.elements.login.selector`
```

but this is not really any advantage over declaring the selectors in a javascript file I can import at the start of the test

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate some? You don't want to navigate to each page with a url because you already land there via button clicks? Are you asking how to reference the elements in the page object with out doing it like `var loginButton = loginPage.elements.login.selector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the elements from each page object without assigning them to variables. The syntax is a little different than you would expect. Here is how I do it in my tests.

Let's say I login to my app, land on a dashboard, and then navigate to an admin menu and verify some element is visible on that page. My test would look something like this (assume I've already setup my page object variables in a `before` hook):

```
'Test example 1': (browser) => {
  loginPage.setValue('@usernameInput', username);
    .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
    .click('@loginBtn');

  dashboardPage.waitForElementVisible('@mainMenu', 1000, () => {
    dashboardPage.click('@mainMenu')
      .click('@adminMenuOption');

    adminMenuPage.verify.visible('@someElement');
  }
}
```

Everywhere you see `@elementName` should match up with what you have named the element in your page object.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of information I was looking for. Thanks a million.

Comment: Yeah just did there. Thanks again